# Consolas not visible in IntelliJ Idea on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: fonts, intellij

Tried installing Consolas on Ubuntu 12.04 as suggested [here](https://superuser.com/a/7912/128645) but the font is not visible in the settings of IntelliJ Idea CE IDE.

[Edit 1]

I also copied the font to `/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.6.0_30/jre/lib/fonts` and did `sudo fc-cache`. Now the font is visible in Gedit but is still not visible in IntelliJ Idea and it not visible in Libre Office3.

Appreciate help.

Comment: Does it help if you place `Consolas.ttf` files into `JDK_HOME/jre/lib/fonts` directory for the JDK installation that is used to run IntelliJ IDEA?

Comment: @CrazyCoder There is only one JDK installation (Sun JAVA) and that is used to run IntelliJ Idea.

Comment: Did you copy all 4 files? `consolaz.ttf`, `consolai.ttf`, `consolab.ttf`, `consola.ttf`. I just tried it, copied these files from Windows machine to the `jre/lib/fonts` and [IDEA sees the Consolas font](http://img43.imageshack.us/img43/8381/20130320025228.png).

Comment: @CrazyCoder No, I will copy all the file now and retry. Which version of Ubuntu did you tried on?

Comment: Ubuntu 12.10, OS version doesn't matter here. I'm running under JDK 1.7, but it will also work on 1.6.

Comment: @CrazyCoder Thnx. It works now and you guys at IntelliJ are awesome. If you put an answer I will accept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consolas font is not just one file, you need to copy all 4 font files into `JDK_HOME/jre/lib/fonts`:

- `consolaz.ttf`
- `consolai.ttf`
- `consolab.ttf`
- `consola.ttf`

Then the font works just fine:

[image: Consolas works!]

Comment: I copied them (those 4 files) from a Windows machine's "Windows/Fonts/" folder and installed using "Font Manager" on Ubuntu, don't forget to restart IntelliJ.